# Implementing Jog using SmoothStreamingMediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, video-streaming, frame-rate

I'm trying to implement a jog function using the SmoothStreamingMediaElement. That is, I want to skip to the next frame of video.

Unfortunately I can't work out how to get the frame rate of the playing video, does anyone know how? I guess I could add an attribute to the media when I transcode it but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the frame rate directly from Silverlight - you need to use another method to pass the value.